# Calculating area of scanned conveyor belt

Tags: geometry

Okay folks, I'm keen to get a response to this brain teaser!!!

Let's say you're looking at a conveyor belt... The width = 2m, and the length = 10m.

Okay... This conveyor belt is moving from right to left at 1m/sec , meanwhile, you're scanning across the conveyor belt from right to left at 2m/sec. (so you're scanning just faster than the conveyor belt is moving).

What is the total area of the conveyor belt that you have scanned.

(Takes 5 seconds to scan from right to left).

OKAY... Next.. let's give you all two more scenarios...

What is the area if:

A) Conveyor belt is moving right to left at 1m/sec, But you are scanning LEFT to RIGHT at 2m/sec?

B) Conveyor belt is moving right to left at 2m/sec, but you are scanning RIGHT to LEFT at 1m/sec (moving slower than the machine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each case you want to find the scanning speed relative to the belt. If scanning in the same direction as the belt is moving this is the difference between belt speed and scanning speed. If scanning in the opposite direction to the belt's movement, this is the sum of belt speed and scanning speed.

And the time to complete a scan is belt length / scanning speed.

Once you have those values, then area scanned = scanning speed relative to belt x time to complete a scan x belt width.

Comment: Thanks Gandalf - this is how I interpret it as well. Here's where the brain fluff kicks in... In Scenario B)... where the scanning is the same direction, but belt is moving faster than the scanner...  Assume

Comment: @GrantRWHumphries As the first sentence says, compute the scanning speed (velocity, really) *relative* to the belt. In this case, you’re effectively scanning left-to-right at a speed equal to the difference.